# Positioning container before the <ul>, to have same height as the first <li> element of the list

Tags: css, flexbox

I have this structure

```
<div>item 0</div>
<ul>
    <li>item 1 <br> some <br> text</li>
    <li>item 2 <br> text </li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I need to position `<div>`, and `<li>`-s next to each other (width: 50%), which is easy. But the div must be same height as the first of `<li>`. **The `<li>` height is unknown**

I'm looking form css only solution. JS is not allowed.
Flexbox is welcome, some extra html markup to, but ul needs to stay ul.

Comment: the short answer : you cannot do this with CSS, you cannot match height on element that don't share the same container. Now you can have some workaround or hacks

Comment: to match which `li` element? it can't match all, please be accurate.

Comment: @skobaljic as i wrote "same height as the first of <li>"

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using CSS-Grid and [sub-grid system](https://css-tricks.com/get-ready-for-display-contents/) using [`display:contents`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents). This feature is not yet supported by all browser but it will come soon:

*Below code tested on chrome and firefox*

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
}

.container > div{
 box-sizing:border-box;
 border:1px solid;
}

ul {
 display:contents;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
ul li {
  display:contents;
}
/*Create a hidden element to fill the first column and keep the content of li in the second one*/
ul li:after {
  content:"";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>item 0</div>
  <ul>
    <li>item 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vitae isus in velit tristique bibendum. Ut porta diam ac eros finibus, ac rhoncus nulla congue. <br> some <br> text</li>
    <li>item 2 <br> text </li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4 <br> text </li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6 <br> text </li>
    <li>item 8</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```